# I'm trying to make my 3d character not rotate on the x axis, the rigidbody rotation constraint doesnt stop the rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
{
   transform.LookAt(target);
}
```

This is what I'm using that causes the object to rotate.

Comment: Well the `Transform` component is not constraint. When dealing with `Rigidbody` you shouldn't set anything via `transform` anyway since this breaks the physics. Even if you would rather use `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` still: Afaik the constraint are only for the "automatic" physics based movements .. not for constraining what you are doing via code

Answer (score 0):

If you manipulate the transform directly you are not using physics. Rotation/movement constraint of the rigidbody component only work for the rotations/movements produced by forces. It makes sense as they are attributes of the rigidbody component.
If you use addforce or addtorque the constraint will work, but not if you set the transform parameters directly, as you are doing with `Transform.LookAt()`.